# Update data of service from multiple components - Observable subscribe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, observable, angular2-services

I want show the title of page in a fixed Navbar file after enter to each page of the site

Files structure:

```
-navbar.ts         (where I display the title, import current title from service)
-titles.service.ts (store the current title )
-component_one.ts  (Send title 1 to service)
-component_two.ts  (Send title 2 to service)
```

---

navbar.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit,} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import {TitleService} from './titles.service';
import {component_one} from '../component_one';
import {component_two} from '../component_two';


@Component({
selector: '[navbar]',
template: require('./navbar.html'),
providers:[TitleService, component_one, component_two]
})

export class Navbar implements OnInit {
 title_page: any;
 _subscription: any;

 constructor(public com_one: component_one, public _titleService:TitleService,  public com_two: component_two){

  this.title_page = _titleService.title_page;
  this._subscription = _titleService.titleChange.subscribe((value) => { 
    this.title_page = value; 
  });  //it's ok?

  }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   this._subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

titles.service.ts

```
import {Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";


@Injectable()
export class TitleService {
  title_page: any;


  titleChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>(); //it is ok?

  constructor() {
  this.title_page = "default title string"; 
  }

  change(title){
  this.title_page = title;
  this.titleChange.next(this.title_page);  //I think is not working
  }
}
```

component_one.ts file 
(after load this page, I want show `'TITLE OF COMPONENT ONE'` on navbar html file )

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TitleService} from '../core/navbar/titles.service';

@Component({
selector: '[component_one]',
template: require('./component_one.html')
providers: [TitleService]
})

export class component_one{
title_page: any;

  constructor(public http: Http, public _titleService: TitleService){
   this.title_page = _titleService.title_page;
   this.changeMyTitle(); //Update Title
  }

  changeMyTitle() {
  this._titleService.change('TITLE OF COMPONENT ONE');
  }

}
```

component_two.ts file (same as component_one with different title string,after load this page, I want show `'TITLE OF COMPONENT two'` on navbar html file )

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TitleService} from '../core/navbar/titles.service';

@Component({
selector: '[component_two]',
template: require('./component_one.html')
providers: [TitleService]
})

export class component_two{
title_page: any;

  constructor(public http: Http, public _titleService: TitleService){
   this.title_page = _titleService.title_page;
   this.changeMyTitle(); //Update Title
  }

  changeMyTitle() {
  this._titleService.change('TITLE OF COMPONENT TWO');
  }

}
```

After enter to first page (component one) still showing `'TITLE OF COMPONENT TWO'`, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use your `TitleService` inside every components `providers` part, it will create a new instance of that service (`providers: [TitleService]`)

So **don't** do this:

```
@Component({
selector: '[component_one]',
template: require('./component_one.html')
providers: [TitleService]
})
```

Instead move the service to `@NgModule` `providers` so that every component inside that module will have the same instance of the providers:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  providers: [MyService]
  declarations: [ App, AnotherApp ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

Full example:https://plnkr.co/edit/qMnXG7oxF3SdTptKHUen?p=info

For older versions,

Put the shared service in the bootstrap function to share it across the app:

```
bootstrap(App, [MyService]);
```

Comment: Just a plus: Providers are shared by model, so, if you provide a service in a module, all children will access the same service instance. But if you provide the service in two modules, each one will have a single instance of the service. To be possible that the two modules have the same instance, you need to provide the service in a module that encapsulate the two others, like app module or another one of your choice.

Comment: Thanks all for fast reply,  sadly I can not use NgModule, is there a way to avoid NgModule?

Comment: @Louis are you using an older version?

Comment: Yes, is 2.0.0-rc.4 and the project is at an advanced state of development.  is there an alternative way to solve it?

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much,. is working fine right now! just last question, how I can send a title and subtitle, e.g.: this.titleChange.next(title, subtitle)  and the service something like: change(title, subtitle){
    this.titleChange.next(title, subtitle); 
}

Comment: @Louis no problem :) if that solved the issue can you mark my answer as accepted please (by clicking the tick to the left of my answer)? :)

Comment: Ready :)   please if you check my last question (edited) it can be very helpful

Comment: @Louis You can't give 2 inputs to the `.next()` function. But! you can give these two parameters in an object. `.next({"title": title, "subtitle":subtitle})` then inside your change function (`change(object){}`) you can select them like, `object.title` or `object.subtitle`. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Perfect! I really appreciate your help